# Launch app in XCode Simulator with permissions for location services usage

Tags: swift, xcode, automated-tests, xcode11, ios-ui-automation

I am using XCode 11 Simulator for autotests.
Is it possible to launch an application with permissions for location services(or any other permissions) turned on from the start?

Would be perfect if there is a way to turn permissions on in simulator without interacting with system alerts, just using some built-in xcode functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this mock: [link](https://robertharrison.ca/posts/2019-06-10-unit-test-cllocationmanager-mock/)